# typescript factory pattern with generics

Tags: typescript-generics

I have a number of models that will be acted upon by their related controller.  However there is a bit of boilerplate I would like to factor out of each controller and I thought I might be able to use a "base controller" with generics.

Hopefully example below shows what I am trying to accomplish - instantiate each controller with a factory method which will result in an instance of the controller being returned containing its specific model instantiated with its defaults.

The challenge specifically is that I can't seem to get past the

> 'X' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

error in the factory.  The abstract class model seems to be the right approach, but open to all suggestions.  [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkBBBAbwCgEqEAHKbGogLgUigEsA7AcwG5LqdBgCEA-C04BXALYh8UftVr0aAYXEIps%20YuqxsnNpPjYoACgCUZAUqoQAFuzAA6IYwQBeBACJ78-N42CAC%205KHkXBDyAGZw%20Fh4hMLWSm7MrNBc3AA0QW7CEjJyULmpKqqF2iVh5OQoaBjCaPiqBtDYyMjyADwAGgB81nkcAG7AUQgA%20tKJyCy9tUr6htDGEKZmNMAAnsjYwLjzVhS21A5OztOznrQ7ewdB4amSIMjssAixJlDblkxNYBabXonR6AyCJ1OCC6iBmBDmvV0pzhhBunHwAHcEL1LEjbFB8BBJFBOJpMQgAUDOO1QVA%20v0zCjkBY8aFwvV0Al4URWtSQV0oAh8AAPKKcXCNZq8mkC7o4bmDSFUZZGb6bO77Q5cwhEY5BJRgSQ0eTq3aalmPGrkGEIYU3eU66X8%20TOL7rH642oAei9SFQnIdyGETo6AqFovw4slgJDtLls2EivIPtsKtWaq2ZoOLEDuusKahrCNJsz91wFoL1FCKfC5CAA)

```
abstract class ModelA {
    propA: string;
    propB?: number;
    propC?: number;
    constructor() {
        this.propA = "here"
    }
}

interface ModelB {
    propA: string,
    propB: number,
    propC: number,
}

class BaseController<X> {

    private _model: X

    constructor(payload: X) {
        this._model = payload
    }

    public factory():BaseController<X>
    {
        let model:X;
        model = new X();
        return new BaseController<X>(model);
    }
}

class ModelAController extends BaseController<ModelA> {
    constructor(payload: ModelA) {
        super(payload);
    }
}

let x = ModelAController.factory();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `factory` as a static method, whereas this is not static.

In order to make it work, you need:

1. to make `factory` static.

```js
class BaseController<X> {

    private _model: X

    constructor(payload: X) {
        this._model = payload
    }

    static factory() // <------- SHOULD BE STATIC
    {
        let model:X;
        model = new X();
        return new BaseController<X>(model);
    }
}
```

2. Change this logic:

```js
        let model:X;
        model = new X();
```

`X` is a generic, it is not a runtime value. It is not allowed to use it as a runtime value;

Consider this example:

```js
abstract class ModelA {
    propA: string;
    propB?: number;
    propC?: number;
    constructor() {
        this.propA = "here"
    }
}

interface ModelB {
    propA: string,
    propB: number,
    propC: number,
}

class BaseController<X> {

    private _model: X

    constructor(payload: X) {
        this._model = payload
    }

    static factory<Model extends new () => any>(Model: Model) {
        return new BaseController(new Model());
    }
}

class ModelAController extends BaseController<ModelA> {
    constructor(payload: ModelA) {
        super(payload);
    }
}

class AnyClass {
    hello = 'Hello'
}

let x = ModelAController.factory(AnyClass);
```

I'm not sure if this example works for you, but at least this compiles.